# Overclocking Asus EEE1008HA PC (AtomN280) running Ubuntu14.04

Tags: asus, overclocking, atom

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on an Asus 1008HA eeePC (Atom N280 @1.6GHz).

I would like to overclock it a bit though since it would "do it good" :)

In previous Ubuntu versions I noticed that some eee Software existed to SW overclock the eeePC Netbooks.

Can I do something similar with Ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EeePC/Using) for using Ubuntu on an eeePC

In order to achieve the overclocking we'll need to compile a kernel module available for download at a Google code site.

You'll most likely need the kernel headers installed as well as build-essential before we can get started:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

Download the source, and create the module:

```
wget http://eeepc-linux.googlecode.com/files/eeepc-linux-0.2.tar.gz
tar -xf eeepc-linux-0.2.tar.gz
cd eeepc-linux/module
make
```

You should now have a file called eee.ko. To make this module a permanent fixture of your current kernel we'll add it to the list of modules that are loaded at boot time and move it to the proper location.

```
sudo mv eee.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/
```

Then edit the /etc/modules file and add the module name eee to the end of the file.

Next register and load the new module into the kernel.

```
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe eee
```

In general, jumping directly to the overclocked speed can cause lockups so smaller jumps toward the speed are suggested. Below is an example of gradually making your way to the overclocked speed:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 85 24 1 > /proc/eee/fsb'
sudo sh -c 'echo 100 24 1 > /proc/eee/fsb'
echo "FSB overclocked to 100MHz"
```

And going back down to the default speeds again:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 85 24 1 > /proc/eee/fsb'
sudo sh -c 'echo 70 24 1 > /proc/eee/fsb'
echo "FSB returned to 70MHz"
```

Comment: ...nice, but use with caution: at the end of the page it says "EeePC/Using (last edited **2010-08**-01 21:19:12 by thomas-horsten-com)".

Comment: Thanx a lot for your feedback. Has anyone tested these with Asus 1008HA PC - Atom N280 @ 1.6GHz and FSB at 667MHz.  Do you think it is feasible to reach 2.1GHz? This would mean that I should overclock the FSB to approx 840MHz, right? If so, how is this translated to "jumps"/setting to /proc/eee/fsb?

Comment: I never tried it, don't have eeePC. I think you may be pussing it a 2.1 ghz as netbooks lack decent cooling, but you can try. To raise your FSB incrimentaly, do it like this (assuming 667 is thge correct starting point, `sudo sh -c 'echo 680 24 1 > /proc/eee/fsb'` Will make it 680mhz, then, `sudo sh -c 'echo 690 24 1 > /proc/eee/fsb'` Gets us to 690 and `sudo sh -c 'echo 700 24 1 > /proc/eee/fsb'` gets us to 700mhz, do you see how I changed the command ? Just the number reprisenting the `FSB` needs changing (the first one(

Comment: slowly run commands based on this to raise the speed until you get what you want (or it crashes), You can try this safely, a raise of 10mhz won't hurt your netbook, run the first command `sudo sh -c 'echo 680 24 1 > /proc/eee/fsb'` then check `lscpu` command, did the `CPU MHz` section increse ? If yes it worked, if no, try another small raise.

Comment: BE CAREFUL TO LARGE INCREASE COULD FRY YOUR MOBO.

Comment: The link : http://eeepc-linux.googlecode.com/files/eeepc-linux-0.2.tar.gz is obsolete... Any other way to overclock?